# Cannot start nodejs server through a 'sudo crontab -e' but it works with 'crontab -e'

Tags: node.js, shell, sh, cron

i need to start a utility written in nodejs lets say in every X minute.
i chose crontab,

my crontab looks like

```
* * * * * /bin/bash /home/michy/run-lola-run.sh
```

and my script

```
  #! /bin/bash
 cd /home/michy
 touch test_before                    #testing to see the script runs
 /usr/bin/node /home/michy/update.js
 touch test_after                    #testing to see the script hanged or crashed
```

Here the 'node update.js'  runs only with **'crontab -e'**  and does not runs with **'sudo crontab -e'**

but my script **run-lola-run.sh**  runs both case, and it creates the files(**test_before,test_after**) in both cases

there is no error reported in **/var/log/syslog**

Thank you

Comment: `crontab -e` edit the crontab file and execute nothing. Did you mean you add the rule as simple user as well as `root`? Try `crontab -l` and `sudo crontab -l` to see if your task if present.

Comment: as i mentioned, the rule added as simple user as well as root. and in both case my .sh is getting invoked and touch those test files. only issue is node server does not start in case of sudo

Comment: You can try to add `set -x` at the beginning of your script to see what's executed at runtime.

Comment: @Édouard Lopez  sure  i will try this, will let you know

Comment: Also the node's help state: `node [options] [ -e script | script.js ] [arguments]` did you try `node -e /home/michy/update.js`?

Comment: i did not try that either